# Как записать объекты из файла в коллекцию?

Tags: java

коллеги!
Прошу помощи в записи объектов из файла в коллекцию.
Объекты известны и уже записаны в файл из другой коллекции. Условно, нужно "достать" объекты из файла и записать в коллекцию. Код ниже не работает, увы сразу переходит на Excepltion.
Спасибо заранее!

```
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("myObjects.txt");
        ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);

        ArrayList<People> temp = new ArrayList();

        while (oi != null) {
            oi.readObject();
            temp.add((People) oi.readObject());
        }

        System.out.println(temp);

        fi.close();
        oi.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error initializing stream");
    }
```

Comment: документация говорит, что ObjectInputStream используется для сериализации/десериализации. Содержимое вашего файла, что вы не показываете, оно содержит сериализованные объекты?

Comment: так же предоставьте сообщение самой `Excepltion`

Answer (score 0):

Основные проблемы в коде -- бесконечный цикл при попытке чтения сериализованных данных, который скорее всего приводит к перехваченному исключению `EOFException`.

Будет предупреждение о "сыром" типе списка в присваивании.  Также следует использовать `try-with-resources` для автоматического закрытия открытых потоков ввода/вывода.

Если задача состоит в чтении каждого второго сериализованного элемента в список (допустим, во входном файле только каждый второй объект является экземпляром `People`):

```java
public static List<People> readPeopleFile(String file) {
    List<People> temp = new ArrayList<>();

    try(ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {

        Object read;
        boolean second = false;

        while ((read = oi.readObject()) != null) {
            if (second) {
                temp.add((People) read);
            }
            second = !second;
        }

        System.out.println(temp);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        System.out.println("File reading completed!");
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading stream: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return temp;
}
```